# Not able to make Call using the Call Function in TabLayout

Tags: android

I have created a tab layout. I want to make a number callable for which I have to define `onCLickListener`, please see the code written in `Tab2` below:
In this error showing is that `MainActivity.this` is not an enclosed class, so what should I write instead of this? (`tab2.xml` is the name of Layout file of Tab)

```
package com.firstapp.admin.herbalteaco;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;

import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by admin on 11/25/2017.
 */

public class Tab2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


private TextView tvCall;
private Button btnLogin;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2 , container , false);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    btnLogin = (Button) btnLogin.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    tvCall = (TextView) tvCall.findViewById(R.id.tvCall);
    tvCall.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+91999999999"));;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    }));

}
```

Comment: Use `getContext()` instead of `MainActivity.this`

Comment: Use getApplicationContext() instead of MainActivity.this

Comment: The app is getting crashed on using getContext()

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getActivity()` inside a class which extends `Fragment`. This will give you the `Activity` instance which owns the fragment. Since `Activity` is a subclass of `Context`, you can use this instance anywhere you need `Context`.

Comment: @A.Rathi This is not a code writing service. Hopefully you can put together the answers given here to figure this out yourself. If not, I suggest you study about inheritance and polymorphism.